# use AsyncStorage inside a _onRefresh?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How is it possible to pull information from AsyncStorage from a `_onRefresh` ?

Here is what i'm trying:

```
_onRefresh = () => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access'); // I cannot do this (I know)
        const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
        this.setState({ refreshing: true });
        axios.get(`http://laundry.test/api/auth/main`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': access,
            }
        }).then(res => {
            this.setState({ laundries: res.data.laundries });
            this.setState({ refreshing: false });
        })
    }
```

how can I perform what I'm trying to do? I need to pull the token to access to my API and grab what I need, without authentication... I won't be pulling anything.

Comment: why you can't do ```AsyncStorage.getItem('access')```?

Comment: Because it does not pull the information.

Comment: it returns a promise you have to wait for it. Since you used ```await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');``` you have to declare ```_onRefresh``` as async.

Comment: I know what you're talking about, but it still does not let me put `async` in front of the `_onRefresh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `_onRefresh` as `async` to solve your issue.

```
_onRefresh = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access");
  const access = "Bearer " + token;
  this.setState({ refreshing: true });
  let response = axios.get(`http://laundry.test/api/auth/main`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: access,
    },
  });
  this.setState({
    laundries: response.data.laundries,
    refreshing: false,
  });
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Accepting this answer, forgot where I had to add that `async` dumb me was trying to put it literally in front of `_onRefresh`. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielLogvin don't think about that. We all make mistakes.